# How to fix the problem of "No ConfigurationProperties annotation" in a Spring Cloud project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerProperties'.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinition(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.register(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:60) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.register(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.java:49) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.atguigu.gateway.GulimallGatewayApplication.main(GulimallGatewayApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
```

This is the detail of exception information, the existing solution of similar problems can't solve this problem. I just a new coder in this scope, please help me.

I just want this sub-project can run smoothly without exceptions and erros, the specific functions will be add by myself later.
Spring Boot version:

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

JDK and Spring Cloud version:

```xml
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
```

These are other important dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-alibaba-nacos-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

The main Application:

```java
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GulimallGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GulimallGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't have that annotation, it is located here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/main/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerClientsProperties.java

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `org.springframework.cloud` dependencies to `3.1.x`. I had the same issue on 3.0.4, but on 3.1.5 and 3.1.6 it was ok. Specifically, in my case the problem was with `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` version.